# django set_cookie does not set cookie in browser

Tags: django, cookies, django-rest-framework

I am writng a drf app, that sets cookie.
I set cookie like this:

```
        serializer = TitleSerializer(result.titles, many=True)
        response = JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
        response.set_cookie("country_code", code)
        return response
```

But when I check request for cookies like this:

```
        if 'country_code' in request.COOKIES:
            print(request.COOKIES['country_code'])
```

I get nothing. I checked response object in browser console and it has them in headers:

```
Set-Cookie
    country_code=unknown; Path=/
```

and in cookies:

```
country_code    
path    "/"
value   "unknown"
```

But when I go to inspect>storage>cookies there is nothing there. Should I set cookies by hand in js or am I doing something wrong in django part? I just googled how to set cookies in django and it seemed like browser should set and send cookies automaticly, so I was curious what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:
in comments under post similar question was suggested, I think it's connected with my problem, but unfortunately it doesen't solve my problem. I tried adding `credentials: 'include'` in my fetch request, but got an error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at .... Reason: header ‘credentials’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response)
```

I tried:

```
response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"]="true"
```

but it also triggers error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ... (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

Comment: Do you have a separate frontend (react, angular, etc.)?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkatyes , yes, I use vue on front

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue or Axios don't store session cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221377/vue-or-axios-dont-store-session-cookie)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkatyes ,  I think it might be the problem, but I already have "CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True" in django settings, or do I need to specify this in request (header?) as well?

Comment: Other than CORS settings you also need to specify some parameters while making the request (for axios `withCredentials = true`, for fetch api `credentials: 'include'`, etc.)

Comment: @AbdulAziz, I tried adding  ` credentials: 'include'` but got error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at .... Reason: header ‘credentials’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response). I also added some settings for django cors headers like `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None` but it didn't help, I tried adding `response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"]="true"` but it trigered error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: ... (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of fetch I used:

```
      axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8001?url="+this.url, {withCredentials:true})
```

like was suggested in this question([Vue or Axios don't store session cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221377/vue-or-axios-dont-store-session-cookie))
Also I added this in django settings

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

and specified samesite parameter like this:

```
response.set_cookie("country_code", code, samesite='Lax')
```

(request will work and without this, but will throw an error about missusing cookie)

Comment: CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True saved my hours, thank you!